# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

[image: Here the directory hierarchy]

[image: The errors]

I am learning Spring MVC and I am following a tutorial on Youtube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2b-NbR48Jo&ab_channel=Telusko.I wanted to display a page that can multiply 2 numbers and return the result. Before that, I just want to print something to see whether these is an error.  I have done exactly same as the tutorial but I still got the errors. I have been searching for the solution for many hours yet I can't find a way to solve my problem.

I am using Eclipse IDE ,apache tomcat 8.0

Here the web.xml

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>

      <servlet-name>viktor</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>


  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>viktor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="multiply">
   <input type="text" name="n1"><br>
   <input type="text" name="n2"><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

viktor-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
">

<ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
<ctx:component-scan base-package="com.viktor"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.viktor</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DemoMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>DemoMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

MultiplyController.java

```
package com.viktor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

@Controller
public class MultiplyController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/multiply")
    public String cnm() {
        
        //System.out.println("adsasd");
        return "display.jsp";
    }

}
```

display.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  im here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding slf4j if the problem is not resolved, then add Maven Dependency in Deployment Assembly.

Comment: I try to add this to pom.xml and it says version missing, so I add the version <version>1.7.2</version>,I have also added the Maven Dependency in Deployment Assembly but the errors still occur. And sometime the error is just HTTP404 (description The requested resource is not available.)